# Undefined variable:

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I got these two errors in my code:

> Notice: Undefined variable: p1 in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\ttt.php on line 61
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\ttt.php on line 61 It is 's turn:

The relevant code is here:

```
//this is within the Board object
function updateBoard(){ 
    if($this->xTurn == True){
        echo "It is " . $p1->username . "'s turn: "; //line 61
    } elseif($this->xTurn == False){
        echo "It is " . $p2->username . "'s turn: ";
    }
}

//This is within the Player object
function __construct($name){
    $this->username = $name;
}

$a   = new Board();
$p1  = new Player($name);
$p2  = new Player($name);
$new = new Game();
$a->updateBoard
```

Whenever I run this, it doesn't echo $p1->username. Any thoughts on how to fix this because I have no idea at this point.

Update: Woops. I left out some important code.

Comment: explain which object calls which and how.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong, you are trying to access the `username` member of `$p1` when `$p1` doesn't exist. Have you checked to make sure `$p1` is initialized within the scope of your first snippet of code before you try to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update board doesn't have `$p1` or `$p2` declared inside the function so they don't exist.  You need to either pass the player objects into the board constructor, set them with a setter method or pass them into the `updateBoard` method.  The first two options would mean that you will have to change them to `$this->p1` and `$this->p2` after assigning the objects to those properties.

```
function updateBoard($p1, $p2){ 
    if($this->xTurn == True){
        echo "It is " . $p1->username . "'s turn: "; //line 61
    } elseif($this->xTurn == False){
        echo "It is " . $p2->username . "'s turn: ";
    }
}

$a   = new Board();
$p1  = new Player($name);
$p2  = new Player($name);
$new = new Game();
$a->updateBoard($p1, $p2);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

this is working fine match with your code what you missed :-

```
class Player
 {
var $username;
function __construct($name){
       $this->username = $name;
      }
 }
$name='rajeev ranjan';
$p1  = new Player($name);
echo $p1->username;
```

Comment: I actually declared the username variable at the beginning of the player class yet it still doesn't work. I even echoed the username variable outside of any object like you did. Still nothing.